# How to improve speed of ajax page loading?

Tags: ajax, jquery-ui, jquery

I am using the following code for ajax page loading

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery('.filter-menu a').live('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('#gallery-ajax').fadeIn(200, function() {
            jQuery('#gallery-ajax').animate({ opacity:0.1 }, 500);
        }).load(link + ' #gallery-ajax', function(){ 
            jQuery('#gallery-ajax').fadeIn(200, function() { 
                jQuery('#gallery-ajax').animate({opacity:1});
            }); 
        });
    });
</script>
```

This is working fine but loads newer contents with very low speed. Can anyone please tell me how to improve its speed of loading newer contents or provide me some alternate jQuery AJAX.

Comment: @jtheman - will that make the ajax faster, and does it work for everyone? If so I'll get right on it myself!

Comment: Make the ajax calls fast by simply trigger ajax function quickly rather than making fadeIn, fadeout and other time consuming JS events

Comment: Can you please give explaination with example

Comment: I could do that but it's good if you could describe what you want to happen. Now the function first fades in and then animates the opacity down to 0.1 which doesn't make sense to me anyway. Then as a callback to the load() function you first fade in and then animate the opacity back to 1.0 which is basically the same. See my suggested answer below, please comment if you want something else to happen...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to take away some of the additional fade functions:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery('.filter-menu a').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = jQuery(this).attr('href');
    jQuery('#gallery-ajax').hide().load(link + ' #gallery-ajax', function(){ 
        jQuery('#gallery-ajax').fadeIn(200); 
    });
});
</script>
```

Of course this is not exactly the same behaviour but it will surely appear faster.